# Implement SAML based SSO with Google and Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, google-apps

I'm implementing SAML based SSO for one of the php web application. I'm using Google as IdP.

I've used Laravel 7 and [laravel-saml2](https://github.com/aacotroneo/laravel-saml2). I configured as per the steps given into it's documentation and added this app in google admin console as SAML app using the steps given here and configured entityId and acs url in saml2_settings.php. I used ngrok to create https domain.

When I hit login url, user is being redirected to google for authentication however when I enters credentials it does not comes back to application and giving following error:
[Error 403: app_not_configured_for_user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dHyz.png)

Following is my saml2_settings file:

```
<?php

// If you choose to use ENV vars to define these values, give this IdP its own env var names
// so you can define different values for each IdP, all starting with 'SAML2_'.$this_idp_env_id
$this_idp_env_id = 'GOOGLE';

//This is variable is for simplesaml example only.
// For real IdP, you must set the url values in the 'idp' config to conform to the IdP's real urls.
$idp_host = env('SAML2_' . $this_idp_env_id . '_IDP_HOST', 'http://localhost:8000/simplesaml');

return $settings = array(

    /*****
     * One Login Settings
     */

    // If 'strict' is True, then the PHP Toolkit will reject unsigned
    // or unencrypted messages if it expects them signed or encrypted
    // Also will reject the messages if not strictly follow the SAML
    // standard: Destination, NameId, Conditions ... are validated too.
    'strict' => true, //@todo: make this depend on laravel config

    // Enable debug mode (to print errors)
    'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),

    // Service Provider Data that we are deploying
    'sp' => array(

        // Specifies constraints on the name identifier to be used to
        // represent the requested subject.
        // Take a look on lib/Saml2/Constants.php to see the NameIdFormat supported
        'NameIDFormat' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent',

        // Usually x509cert and privateKey of the SP are provided by files placed at
        // the certs folder. But we can also provide them with the following parameters
        'x509cert' => env('SAML2_' . $this_idp_env_id . '_SP_x509', ''),
        'privateKey' => env('SAML2_' . $this_idp_env_id . '_SP_PRIVATEKEY', ''),

        // Identifier (URI) of the SP entity.
        // Leave blank to use the '{idpName}_metadata' route, e.g. 'test_metadata'.
        'entityId' => env('SAML2_' . $this_idp_env_id . '_SP_ENTITYID', ''),

        // Specifies info about where and how the <AuthnResponse> message MUST be
        // returned to the requester, in this case our SP.
        'assertionConsumerService' => array(
            // URL Location where the <Response> from the IdP will be returned,
            // using HTTP-POST binding.
            // Leave blank to use the '{idpName}_acs' route, e.g. 'test_acs'
            'url' => '',
        ),
        // Specifies info about where and how the <Logout Response> message MUST be
        // returned to the requester, in this case our SP.
        // Remove this part to not include any URL Location in the metadata.
        'singleLogoutService' => array(
            // URL Location where the <Response> from the IdP will be returned,
            // using HTTP-Redirect binding.
            // Leave blank to use the '{idpName}_sls' route, e.g. 'test_sls'
            'url' => '',
        ),
    ),

    // Identity Provider Data that we want connect with our SP
    'idp' => array(
        // Identifier of the IdP entity  (must be a URI)
        'entityId' => env('SAML2_' . $this_idp_env_id . '_IDP_ENTITYID', $idp_host . '/saml2/idp/metadata.php'),
        // SSO endpoint info of the IdP. (Authentication Request protocol)
        'singleSignOnService' => array(
            // URL Target of the IdP where the SP will send the Authentication Request Message,
            // using HTTP-Redirect binding.
            'url' => env('SAML2_' . $this_idp_env_id . '_IDP_SSO_URL', $idp_host . '/saml2/idp/SSOService.php'),
        ),
        // SLO endpoint info of the IdP.
        'singleLogoutService' => array(
            // URL Location of the IdP where the SP will send the SLO Request,
            // using HTTP-Redirect binding.
            'url' => env('SAML2_' . $this_idp_env_id . '_IDP_SL_URL', $idp_host . '/saml2/idp/SingleLogoutService.php'),
        ),
        // Public x509 certificate of the IdP
        'x509cert' => env('SAML2_' . $this_idp_env_id . '_IDP_x509', 'MIID/TCCAuWgAwIBAgIJAI4R3WyjjmB1MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIGUMQswCQYDVQQGEwJBUjEVMBMGA1UECAwMQnVlbm9zIEFpcmVzMRUwEwYDVQQHDAxCdWVub3MgQWlyZXMxDDAKBgNVBAoMA1NJVTERMA8GA1UECwwIU2lzdGVtYXMxFDASBgNVBAMMC09yZy5TaXUuQ29tMSAwHgYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFhFhZG1pbmlAc2l1LmVkdS5hcjAeFw0xNDEyMDExNDM2MjVaFw0yNDExMzAxNDM2MjVaMIGUMQswCQYDVQQGEwJBUjEVMBMGA1UECAwMQnVlbm9zIEFpcmVzMRUwEwYDVQQHDAxCdWVub3MgQWlyZXMxDDAKBgNVBAoMA1NJVTERMA8GA1UECwwIU2lzdGVtYXMxFDASBgNVBAMMC09yZy5TaXUuQ29tMSAwHgYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFhFhZG1pbmlAc2l1LmVkdS5hcjCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAMbzW/EpEv+qqZzfT1Buwjg9nnNNVrxkCfuR9fQiQw2tSouS5X37W5h7RmchRt54wsm046PDKtbSz1NpZT2GkmHN37yALW2lY7MyVUC7itv9vDAUsFr0EfKIdCKgxCKjrzkZ5ImbNvjxf7eA77PPGJnQ/UwXY7W+cvLkirp0K5uWpDk+nac5W0JXOCFR1BpPUJRbz2jFIEHyChRt7nsJZH6ejzNqK9lABEC76htNy1Ll/D3tUoPaqo8VlKW3N3MZE0DB9O7g65DmZIIlFqkaMH3ALd8adodJtOvqfDU/A6SxuwMfwDYPjoucykGDu1etRZ7dF2gd+W+1Pn7yizPT1q8CAwEAAaNQME4wHQYDVR0OBBYEFPsn8tUHN8XXf23ig5Qro3beP8BuMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFPsn8tUHN8XXf23ig5Qro3beP8BuMAwGA1UdEwQFMAMBAf8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBAGu60odWFiK+DkQekozGnlpNBQz5lQ/bwmOWdktnQj6HYXu43e7sh9oZWArLYHEOyMUekKQAxOK51vbTHzzw66BZU91/nqvaOBfkJyZKGfluHbD0/hfOl/D5kONqI9kyTu4wkLQcYGyuIi75CJs15uA03FSuULQdY/Liv+czS/XYDyvtSLnu43VuAQWN321PQNhuGueIaLJANb2C5qq5ilTBUw6PxY9Z+vtMjAjTJGKEkE/tQs7CvzLPKXX3KTD9lIILmX5yUC3dLgjVKi1KGDqNApYGOMtjr5eoxPQrqDBmyx3flcy0dQTdLXud3UjWVW3N0PYgJtw5yBsS74QTGD4='),
        /*
         *  Instead of use the whole x509cert you can use a fingerprint
         *  (openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint -in "idp.crt" to generate it)
         */
        // 'certFingerprint' => '',

        /**
     * (Optional) Enable Multi-Cert signing/encryption
     * In some scenarios the IdP uses different certificates for
     * signing/encryption, or is under key rollover phase and
     * more than one certificate is published on IdP metadata.
     * In order to handle that the toolkit offers that parameter.
     * (when used, 'x509cert' and 'certFingerprint' values are
     * ignored).
     */

        //'x509certMulti'=>array(
        //    'signing'=>array(
        //      0=>env('SAML2_'.$this_idp_env_id.'_IDP_x509_SIGNING_0',''),
        //    ),
        //    'encryption'=>array(
        //      0=>env('SAML2_'.$this_idp_env_id.'_IDP_x509_ENCRYPTION_0',''),
        //    ),
        //  ),

    ),



    /***
     *
     *  OneLogin advanced settings
     *
     *
     */
    // Security settings
    'security' => array(

        /** signatures and encryptions offered */

        // Indicates that the nameID of the <samlp:logoutRequest> sent by this SP
        // will be encrypted.
        'nameIdEncrypted' => false,

        // Indicates whether the <samlp:AuthnRequest> messages sent by this SP
        // will be signed.              [The Metadata of the SP will offer this info]
        'authnRequestsSigned' => false,

        // Indicates whether the <samlp:logoutRequest> messages sent by this SP
        // will be signed.
        'logoutRequestSigned' => false,

        // Indicates whether the <samlp:logoutResponse> messages sent by this SP
        // will be signed.
        'logoutResponseSigned' => false,

        /* Sign the Metadata
         False || True (use sp certs) || array (
                                                    keyFileName => 'metadata.key',
                                                    certFileName => 'metadata.crt'
                                                )
        */
        'signMetadata' => false,


        /** signatures and encryptions required **/

        // Indicates a requirement for the <samlp:Response>, <samlp:LogoutRequest> and
        // <samlp:LogoutResponse> elements received by this SP to be signed.
        'wantMessagesSigned' => false,

        // Indicates a requirement for the <saml:Assertion> elements received by
        // this SP to be signed.        [The Metadata of the SP will offer this info]
        'wantAssertionsSigned' => false,

        // Indicates a requirement for the NameID received by
        // this SP to be encrypted.
        'wantNameIdEncrypted' => false,

        // Authentication context.
        // Set to false and no AuthContext will be sent in the AuthNRequest,
        // Set true or don't present thi parameter and you will get an AuthContext 'exact' 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport'
        // Set an array with the possible auth context values: array ('urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password', 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:X509'),
        'requestedAuthnContext' => true,
    ),

    // Contact information template, it is recommended to suply a technical and support contacts
    'contactPerson' => array(
        'technical' => array(
            'givenName' => 'name',
            'emailAddress' => 'no@reply.com'
        ),
        'support' => array(
            'givenName' => 'Support',
            'emailAddress' => 'no@reply.com'
        ),
    ),

    // Organization information template, the info in en_US lang is recomended, add more if required
    'organization' => array(
        'en-US' => array(
            'name' => 'Name',
            'displayname' => 'Display Name',
            'url' => 'http://url'
        ),
    ),

    /* Interoperable SAML 2.0 Web Browser SSO Profile [saml2int]   http://saml2int.org/profile/current

   'authnRequestsSigned' => false,    // SP SHOULD NOT sign the <samlp:AuthnRequest>,
                                      // MUST NOT assume that the IdP validates the sign
   'wantAssertionsSigned' => true,
   'wantAssertionsEncrypted' => true, // MUST be enabled if SSL/HTTPs is disabled
   'wantNameIdEncrypted' => false,
*/

);
```

and .env file

```
SAML2_GOOGLE_IDP_HOST =https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2?idpid=C00w1xt15
SAML2_GOOGLE_IDP_SSO_URL =https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2/idp?idpid=C00w1xt15
SAML2_GOOGLE_IDP_SL_URL =
SAML2_GOOGLE_IDP_x509 =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
```

This is my Google Cert

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RLda.png)

Can someone please help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: did you get it solved?

Comment: After a long time, I just read it again, it seems my fault was using an app that has expired in google's trial

Answer (score 2):

You have to set up your app in Google IdP for it to recognize requests.

The first few steps in [this tutorial](https://docs.helloid.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002885874-Configure-Google-G-Suite-as-a-SAML-IdP) seems like a good start.